# If two cubes with different mass but similar size fall from the same height in the presence of air resistance, which reaches first or is it the same?

Tags: forces

Basically if the two box of same volume but one is heavier than the other which falls to the ground the first in the presence of air resistance ?

Comment: If you drop a bowling ball and a balloon with the same volume from the same height, which one will hit the ground first ?

Answer (score 0):

The heavier one reaches the ground first.

First, realize F=G*(Mm/r^2) is the gravitational force both objects "feel". Note that the force is proportional to each object's mass. The small m in the equation cancels with the small m in Newton's second law (F=ma) for both. that's why Two objects fall at the same speed without air (those two m are actually not the same thing but it will do for us).

When air resistance is added to the mix, because the two are similar in size they will experience the same force acting on them (rather then proportional like before), then simply from F=ma the outcome is clear.